# Bootstrap mobile navbar dropdown is transparent

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Django-powered Bootstrap website. I'm using the theme Modern Business by Start Bootstrap.

This is how it looks on [the live sample](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/services.html):
[image: How it is on the live sample]

This is how it looks on [my website](http://rc.ocdebate.com) (note the resources text below the logo):
[image: How it looks on my website]

Here's my code for the navbar.

```
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarExample" aria-controls="navbarExample" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="container" style="height: 48px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="{% static 'web/img/header-logo-2.png' %}" height="70px" style="height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarExample">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        About
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Board of Directors</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="about-staff">Executive Administration</a>
                    </div>
                </li>-->
                <!--<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="schools">Schools</a>
                </li>-->
                <!--<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>-->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Resources
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                           href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngzaxhg4gqlibpx/2016-2017%20OCDL%20Charter.pdf?dl=0"
                           target="_blank">League Charter</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                           href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nh1a93og93vqt0/OCDL%20Affidavit%202015-2016.pdf?dl=0"
                           target="_blank">Student Agreement</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                           href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/en1t2ek23rxzxlj/OCDL%20Judges%20Affidavit.pdf?dl=0"
                           target="_blank">Judge Agreement</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                           href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwxsnbpmc29vylq/OCDL%20Judge%20Guide-11-4-15.pdf?dl=0"
                           target="_blank">Judge Guide</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                           href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkcvaggipfn91fi/Flow%20Chart%2C%20Orange%20County%20Debate%20League.docx?dl=0"
                           target="_blank">Blank Flowchart</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"
                           href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/vphswry1d4rgm0d/Speaker%20Performance%20Rubric%2C%20Orange%20County%20Debate%20League.pdf?dl=0"
                           target="_blank">OCDL Rubric</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Blog
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                    </div>
                </li>-->
                <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Other Pages
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                    </div>
                </li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add media query for particular screen width. In your case bootstrap navbar will change at a screen width of 768px, so just add this to your css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 787px) {
    .navbar-inverse {
         opacity: 0.9;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it doesn't seem to have worked. Here's the link to the CSS file for the navbar: https://ocdl.s3.amazonaws.com/web/css/nav-temp.css. Am I missing something?